# cannot access ethers.js providers when using import statement in typescript

Tags: typescript, ethers.js, ts-node

I am running typescript using ts-node and try to use ethers.js provider:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
```

it gets the following error:

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: - error TS2339: Property 'providers' does not exist on type 'typeof import

The code works using:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
```

but I need es6 format to run the script since my other module run on es6, otherwise I have to convert all other dependencies to use "require" statement, which is too much.

ethers.js doc says that it can run on es6. Is it because I use ts-node?

Comment: did you execute `npm install --save-dev @types/ethers`

Comment: I try that statement, it fails: npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fethers - Not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this ethers.js closed issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3794)this is fixed by

executing:

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider();
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

## FreeCodeCamp Solidity Course Devs

In Ethers v6, `ethers.provider*` was replaced with `ethers.*`:

> In addition to all the ethers.providers.* being moved to ethers.*, the biggest change developers need to keep in mind is that Web3Provider (which historically was used to wrap link-web3 providers) is now called BrowserProvider which is designed to wrap EIP-1193 providers, which is the standard that both modern Web3.js and injected providers offer.

Here is the GitHub issue asking about this: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3794

Here is the link to the migration guide: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/#migrate-providers